# Excel VBA: Add a scatter chart to worksheet as object

Tags: vba, excel, charts

<strike>I am looking to create a scatter chart that, on button press, creates a scatter chart in `Sheet 1` and uses `A2:A11` as the `x` values and `B2:B11` as the `y` values.</strike>

Using code at the bottom allows me to create a scatter chart based off of the values in `A1:B3` (got this from [here](http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/vba/263264/263965/xy-scatter-curve/)). Its close, but not exactly what I'm looking for. How can I tweak this to suit my needs?

I got it set up now so the chart is made, based on the values I want, but I can not get it to appear as an object in `Sheet 1`. How do I do this? `.Location xlLocationAsObject` doesn't seem to work.

```
Private Sub chartButton_Click()
    ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveChart
        'Data?
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Scatter Chart"""
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$11"
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$11"

        'Location
        'DON'T KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE
        '.location xlLocationAsObject doesn't work!

        'Titles
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Scatter Chart"
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "X values"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Y values"
        .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True

        'Formatting
        .Axes(xlCategory).HasMinorGridlines = False
        .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True
        .Axes(xlValue).HasMinorGridlines = False
        .HasLegend = False

    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code as written adds a chart as a `Chart Sheet`, not as a chart on a `Worksheet`

Try this:

Replace

```
ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveChart
```

with

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim chrt As Chart

Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set chrt = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
With chrt
```

Then you can control its position and size with

```
    .ChartArea.Left
    .ChartArea.Top 
    .ChartArea.Height
    .ChartArea.Width
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Chart.Location`, you need to specify the location:

```
.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Sheet1"
```